# Story in Star Trek novel - Shatner, Nimoy, etc beam to the real Enterprise

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, novel

There was a story I vaguely remember from decades ago that appeared in a Star Trek novel of episodes that might-have-been (but never were actually produced), with the story line that the actors from the set of Star Trek somehow beam onto the real USS Enterprise, and have to deal with all the differences between TV set and actual (highly advanced) technology.

If that story is still accessible today, either on-line or in a purchase-able book, I'd be most interested.  Thanks!

Comment: could be one from the amateur submission series "Strange New Worlds"

Comment: Is this the one where (Captain Kirk) William Shatner -- the actor is shocked to hear the door and instrument sounds? He and Nimoy (and maybe others) as the actors, suddenly find themselves about an actual Starship Enterprise? If so, it is from the first series of novels.

Comment: @Willow -- yes, I remember the door sounds specifically, that instead of being sound effects added in post-production, the doors actually sounded that way.  I'm not familiar with the various series of novels (beyond having read some of them way too long ago to have any at hand); any links you could offer would be great!

Comment: I have been searching and I must be incorrect, Ralph. I cannot find the book anywhere, maybe because though I liked the idea, it wasn't really very good. I used ST novels to teach literacy to teens. Worked like a charm! Anyway, you aren't mad, I remember it too. It must have been not have been in the regular series of novels endorsed by Paramount.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look for [*Star Trek: The New Voyages*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553027190); the story you want is "Visit to a Weird Planet Revisited"

> *Shatner nodded, and they each took one of Nimoy’s arms, prepared to
>   hustle him out into the corridor. By this time, however, he too had
>   counted up the costs of scene design and construction. James Doohan
>   could have gone on improvising in the tones of outraged Scottishness
>   all day without breaking, but Matt Jeffries just didn’t have the
>   budget to have built the room they were in.*
>
> ***The door swooshed open at their approach, and all three knew, even
>   before they got past it, that they were on board the Enterprise. The
>   pneumatic door-sound was supposed to be added by Glen Glenn Sound.
>   They had never before heard it in real life.*** The door swooshed shut
>   behind them, and they stood still for a moment, feeling totally lost.
>
> *“Nice going, De,” said Shatner, trying to recover some poise. “Now,
>   how the hell do we find the Sickbay?”*
>
> *“Go to the elevator and say ‘Sickbay’?” suggested Kelley.*

Comment: @Valorum - thanks; I only had it in hardcopy, so nothing to cutpaste from.

Comment: Aha -- this is it. I'll thank you, too!

Comment: @Valorum: I actually disagree with your second edit; book titles should be in italic (and story titles in quotes), and the semicolon was in fact used correctly.

Comment: It's based on an earlier story called "Visit to a Weird Planet", in which Kirk, Spock, and McCoy beam down to the Paramount sound stage. https://fanlore.org/wiki/Visit_to_a_Weird_Planet

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - If you have an issue with an edit, you can use the edit button (below your answer) to resolve it. That's what it's there for

Comment: @Valorum - 'edit' was greyed out at the time; no idea why, or why it wasn't when I tried just now.

Comment: @ Jeff Zeitlin I wonder if that story in any way influenced the movie Galaxy Quest

Comment: @Gray - No way to know, but ... :)