# Short story where Star Trek: The Next Generation was real, actors on set have to adapt to the roles they take

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, short-stories

There was a short story once where it started off with a behind-the-scenes story of the filming of a Star Trek episode, and actors are referred to by their actual names.  During the shoot, something happens, and they are on the real Enterprise-D.

This looks similar to:

[Story in Star Trek novel - Shatner, Nimoy, etc beam to the real Enterprise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158982/story-in-star-trek-novel-shatner-nimoy-etc-beam-to-the-real-enterprise)

But for TNG.   There was some mention made of Brent Spiner's/Data's relationship with his fans.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost certainly thinking of ["Revisiting a Visit to a Weird Planet Revisited"](http://web.archive.org/web/20170215212005/http://www.sff.net/people/hoosier.red/revisiting/revisiting1.html), which was originally on SFF.net but now only on the Wayback Machine.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  Never read it before and enjoyed it muchly.